# HOM12L100 in a skoolie

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

Power (shore power) comes via extension cord from home outlet, generator or campground feed. External connection goes to GP-TS transfer switch. That in tun powers standalone battery charger, inverter (which is offline) and AC panel. Panel has 6 circuit breakers. Breakers 1,3 and 5 work fine. Breakers 2,4 and six have not power. Correct grounding kit for this box is installed. Feed wires are 3 wire 8 ga. Green wire connected to ground. White wires connected to neutral. I'm thinking maybe Y jumping black cables to both sides but I sure would like your input.

Comment: That GP-TS is a nice piece of kit for the price.  Is it a TS-30 or TS-50?

Comment: Is your shore power 30A@120V (3 prong plug) or 50A@240V? (4 prong plug)

Comment: Shore connection is 30 amp (3 wire) currently with adapter to 110 which is connected by 12ga extension cord to gfi receptacle in house.

Answer (score 2):

By your statement of 3-wire feeder (neutral and ground being two), I infer the GP-TS-30 (30A).

#8 is overkill for 30A (which is fine) and not enough for 50A with NM or UF cable (but is OK for 50A with THHN).

> I'm thinking maybe Y jumping black cables to both sides but I sure would like your input.

Yes. That is what you need to do.  Pigtail it, do not double-lug.  You need #10 for the pigtails.

If the physical space allows, you can thread *through* one lug and then go to the other lug, removing the insulation where it is under the lug. The run between lugs must be insulated.

Consider adding HOM1RK tie-down kits to the breakers to remove possibility of them popping out due to road vibration. I really wish Pushmatic was still in business, all their breakers bolted down.

---

If you find yourself in a jam and need 8 spaces instead of six, FYI, the QO816L100 panels use the same outer box. You'd just need to swap guts and cover, very easy. But the breakers are more expensive.

Comment: OP's response: Thanks for your input problem is solved. Created Y pigtail with 8ga wire (it's what I had) and taped together at the end and used the correct wirenut and twisted like Chubby Checkers. All is good.